# Evaluation of the multiplication of the metric tensors

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

Define $$g_{\mu\nu}=g^{\mu\nu}=\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 & 0 &0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 &0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 &0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 &-1 \end{array} \right)$$to be the standard metric tensor in flat spacetime. Assume the summation rule for four index. It was asked to evaluate $$g^{\mu\nu}g_{\nu\rho}g^{\rho\mu}.$$ Then what I got is $$\delta^{\mu}_{\rho}g^{\rho\mu}=g^{\mu\mu}.$$
Actually, since there is no free index, I would like to sum it, but it gets both index up, which cannot be summed conventionally. What exactly is $g^{\mu\mu}$, is it still a second rank tensor or is it a scalar? Thank you.

Comment: That loks like a typo - where did you get that from? You're right that $g^{\mu\mu}$ is ill-formed under the ususal conventions, or at least unusual and in need of clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Toffomat says, that looks like a typo. At least, it's not something that one would normally write. If the author doesn't say anything about it, it is probably a typo. However, if I were *forced* to interpret the expression $g^{\mu\mu}$ without any commentary, I'd say that the symbol would represent the four entries of the diagonal, one for each possible value of $\mu$, so in that sense it would be a set of four scalars.

Comment: Im sorry, but $g^{\mu \mu}$ is not a valid expression. It would require a fixed coordinate basis

Comment: @ContraKinta I see what you mean, in the sense that is not something that one would normally write, but the expression *can* be given an interpretation and I'd say that the diagonal is the closest one to mathematical prsctice (and have actually seen it used by people, although it always came together with a remark about the meaning). I agree that my unremarked answer was misleading. I hope it's better now. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: The diagonal is what you would get if, for example, you used the 'einsum' function in python/numpy